# Why is Find object searching through the whole data instead of a specified Range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Vba(and coding in general) and have written a very basic macro to find out "wood" inside a particular column from a larger set of data, however when I try to run it, it's still searching from the whole data set instead of the specified column.

I started with keeping the range of Cel to the whole data set, and then just narrowed it to the third column. However, when I remove the find element the immediate window shows me the address of cells in the third column, just as I want, but as soon as I use Find, it searches through the whole dataset.
I've tried defining propertied in Find object such as After and SearchOrder, but then it shows an error.

```
Dim emptyrow As Long
emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
Dim Cel As Range
Dim n As Integer
Set Cel = Range("C2:C54")

For n = 2 To emptyrow
   Debug.Print (Cel.Cells(n,3).Find("wood","C2",,,xlByColumn).Address)
Next n
```

On using properties of Find, I get a type mismatch error.

Comment: Without the Loop, try `Debug.Print Cel.Find("wood").Address`

Comment: The `After` parameter should be a Range object, not an address string (or just omit it). Also note that you are currently searching column E.

Comment: You don't need the loop, you can search the whole range in one go, but your code will error if "wood" is not found. Also `Cel.Cells(n,3)` is equivalent to E4 when n=2 as this is a relative reference.

Comment: @Mikku, without the loop it just returns the first value it encounters, and doesn't search for the rest of the values.

Comment: @KushagraMittal .. See the Answer

Comment: There are plenty of examples online on how to do this.

Comment: @Mikku, yes please. What I actually wanna do is search through the particular column to find wood values, and then use those cells to obtain the data from the first column and corresponding row. Right now I am just trying to select and get the address of wood values.

Comment: @KushagraMittal .. You will get all those addresses from the below address.

Comment: @SJR, noted and corrected the cell reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you want to do with the results, but here are a couple of possible outputs.

```
Sub xx()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String, v() As Variant, i As Long

With Range("C2:C54")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="Wood", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                      Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            Debug.Print rFind.Offset(, -2).Value 'column A value in immediate window
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve v(1 To i)
            v(i) = rFind.Offset(, -2).Value      'or store values in an array
            Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
         Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

MsgBox Join(v, ", ")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
Sub fnd_all_wood()

Dim c As Range
Dim firstaddress As String

With Range("C2:C54")
     Set c = .Find("wood", LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Do
            Debug.Print c.Address
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstaddress
      End If
DoneFinding:

MsgBox "Done All"
End With

End Sub
```

This will print all the Cell Address in Range C2:C54 where it finds `Wood`

More information about the Formula [Range.FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) in the Link.

---

**Update:**

You can change the line `Debug.Print c.Address` to any other code where you can get the row by `c.row` and use it to get the other values like `cells(c.row,1)` to get the value from Ist column.

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: This is fine, though to be safe I think better to specify more Find parameters in case they are not what you expect.

Comment: Idk why, but as I try to run your code, it's giving me a run time error '91'. Object variable or With block variable not set. @Mikku

Comment: @KushagraMittal .. On which line ? But it's fine, You can use the one provided by SJR.

Comment: It's on 
firstaddress = c.Address.
I just want to identify why am I getting this error, and avoid it in my future programs.

Comment: Maybe that was the Error that SJR corrected. Try the Updated Code. It was because `firstaddress` should be declared as String, i by mistake declared it as Range.